# IONIC - HTTP Post request not working, problems with headers maybe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

My POST request wont work to contact a local API, Local API work with get request without problems

```
public PostChat(club: string, id, rep:string) {
        console.log("begin");
        let headers = new Headers(
        {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        let data = JSON.stringify({
            club : club,
            id: id,
            rep: rep
        });

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.post(`${this.baseUrlChat}senduser.php`, data, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then((response) =>
            {
                console.log('API Response : ', response.json());

            })
            .catch((error) =>
            {
                console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
            });
        });
    }
```

Actual error message :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://192.168.43.58/api/chat/senduser.php' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
>   header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: This isn't an Ionic Issue, its an issue on your sever, which doesn't allow cross origin response

Answer (score 0):

You need to Handle CORS in your backend to accept cross origin request.

Like this:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Go though this [Article](https://blog.ls-al.com/cors-example-with-php/)

Comment: Already have ... all the get request from my app to my API are working fine juste the post method